# How to go about racking the introduction to new warnings

Tags: visual-studio, logging, warnings

For a rather large codebase I am thinking about creating a tool that tracks new warnings as they get committed so that we can see exactly where each were introduced and by whom.

Is the only viable way(that I can think of) to simply parse the output log each time, comparing this to a previous one and append the new warnings.

There doesn't seem to be much that I can find in terms of identifying new warnings, via google search.

Comment: All warnings should be eliminated *before* code is committed.

Comment: @G.M.: issue is when your upgrade your compiler (or static tool analyzer).

Comment: Issue to compare both log is to identify same issue: line numbers might change, file might be renamed, code might be moved.

Comment: @Jarod42 Even so, I'd argue the code should originally have been committed without warning.  When subsequently upgrading the toolchain (or whatever) a new workspace is pulled, the warnings fixed and the new code committed without warnings.  I know I'm being a bit 'tedious' but I'm just very wary of the text `"...tracks new warnings as they get committed..."`.

Comment: @G.M.: With huge code base, fixing old warnings might be endless or too long (or even be in "restricted" code with split teams) to allow upgrading then.

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately that is the situation the codebase is in. It's far too large and generates too many warnings to correct them all.